# Assign a value to all variables that start with certain string

Tags: javascript, variables, find, global, assign

**[WARNING! Bad idea ahead]**

I know this is probably a weird question, but I'm writing a script (in JavaScript) that detects surveys. So, this certain kind of survey declares a bunch of variables that start with a certain string, and then a random number appended to the name, like so:

```
variableName_465;
variableName_212;
variableName_123;
```

So let's assume all of them are set to false, how do I set them all to true?
I have this loop that logs variables in the global scope.

```
for ( var i in window ) 
{
    console.log(i, typeof window[i], window[i]);
}
```

But `i = true;` inside of the for loop doesn't change the actual variable, I guess that I'm actually creating a new one.

I really have no clue as to if this is doable. I'd be very grateful with your help, thanks.

Comment: It's possible, but it's a horrible idea that you should rethink.

Comment: I had a hunch about the idea being horrible, and I guess one of the reasons is that you would probably interfere with other scripts or maybe it'd be too slow/unreliable. Is this right? What other things are wrong about it? Nonetheless, I want to find out how to do it, I found that setting those variables to its opposite actually defeats the whole script! (which is what I want to do). I guess I want to find out just for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify `window[i]` (the value of variable `i`), not `i` (the variable name). So you can do something like this:

```
for (var i in window) {
    if (i.indexOf('variableName') == 0){
        window[i] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, it wasn't a complicated matter indeed. I think maybe I should add a disclaimer to my post.